# What are the common cases of disputes where buyer is found guilty in cryptocurrency trade?

Tags: client, buy-bitcoins, historical-trade-data, trade

I am working on dispute management of crytocurrency trade and I am new in this field.

I want to know what are the cases where a buyer is found guilty in a cryptocurrency trade whether it is on localbitcoin.com or anywhere else.

It will be a good help for me.

Comment: The best thing to do would be to consult a lawyer so you can understand the law, your rights, and only engage in behavior you feel meets the level of risk you're willing to assume.